# How do we determine whether the tight binding model is valid for a material?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, tight-binding

Right now I know that the tight binding model applies when electrons are tightly localized around the ions in the material. How do we determine whether the electrons are actually tightly localized for a real material such as graphene?

What would be the relevant experimental quantity to examine?

Conversely, in what case does the tight-binding approximation fail with what parameters?

The quantities I am currently considering are the width of the bands and how much they overlap?

Comment: I think, in practice, people simply assume that the model works, calculate all its properties, and see to what extent they agree with experiments.